# Is there possibility to generate pdf file in weasyprint with chineese letters?

Tags: python, linux, weasyprint

I have html code like this:

```
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><h1>德德德</h1>
```

I wish to convert it to pdf with weasyprint, but when I open generated file I get:

```
5FB7 5FB7 5FB7
```

In rectangles.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

When I have tried to load custom font with such code:

```
    css = CSS(string='''
          @font-face {
          font-family: 'fonts-japanese-gothic';
          src: url('/share/fonts/truetype/unfonts-core/UnDotum.ttf') format('truetype');
                     }
''', font_config=font)
```

I got such error:

```
Ignored `src: url("/share/fonts/truetype/unfonts-core/UnDotum.ttf") format("truetype")` at 3:3, Relative URI reference without a base URI: '/share/fonts/truetype/unfonts-core/UnDotum.ttf'.
```

Comment: You should check your encoding settings for the PDF, I'm unfamiliar with Weasyprint, but familiar with the rectangle characters.

Comment: I have checked. Maybe it is related to wrong loading of font.

Comment: I could not reproduce this, using the exact HTML you posted yielded to me the expected result. I assume this is an issue with the fonts of your system. Maybe try opening the PDF on a different computer to see if the file looks as expected.